# I don't quite understand this template function in Python

Tags: python

```
#template.py

import fileinput, re

field_pat = re.compile(r'\[(.+?)\]')

scope = {}

def replacement(match):
    code = match.group(1)
    try:
        return str(eval(code, scope))
    except SyntaxError:
        exec code in scope
        return

lines = []
for line in fileinput.input():
    lines.append(line)
text = ''.join(lines)

print field_pat.sub(replacement, text)
```

---

```
#text.py

[x = 1]
[y = 2]
The sum of [x] and [y] is [x + y]
```

---

If I execute "python template.py text.py" in command line, if will print 'The sum of 1 and 2 is 3'. In the file template.py, replacement() is a function, why it is an argument of sub() function and it does not have argument?(it's supposed to take an match object as argument) And also, what is the scope dictionary for if it is empty??
Many thanks!!!

Comment: the replacement function in pat_field.sub() does have an argument. It's called 'text'.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Yes I understand replacement here is used as a string, and the function returns a string. But if the function does not take a match object as argument, how can it return a string?

Answer (score 4):

So you are asking several questions about this code. What it is intended to do is quite clear: It is intended to

1. read the input file,
2. merge it into one line,
3. For each expression in square brackets found in that line
4. call `eval(code,scope)`, where `code` is the expression in brackets.

Now for your specific questions:

> 1. replacement() is a function, why it is an argument of sub() function and it does not have argument?

Because that is how [`sub()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) works

> re.**sub**(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
>
> Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping occurrences of pattern in *string* by the replacement
>   *repl*. If the pattern isn’t found, *string* is returned unchanged. *repl*
>   can be a string **or a function**; [...]
>   If *repl* is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping
>   occurrence of *pattern*. The function takes a single match object
>   argument, and returns the replacement string.

Here pattern is the `self` argument  and `repl` is set to our `replacement()` function. It will receive the match object as an argument that contains references to each matched group.

> 2. And also, what is the scope dictionary for if it is empty?

That is the dictionary that will be used to keep track of variable assignments. It will be supplied as the second argument to `eval()`.

For illustration here is a trace of execution of the `replacement()` function. The function is executed exactly 5 times.

```
Evaluating 'x = 1', scope = []
Evaluating 'y = 2', scope = ['x : 1']
Evaluating 'x', scope = ['x : 1', 'y : 2']
Evaluating 'y', scope = ['x : 1', 'y : 2']
Evaluating 'x + y', scope = ['x : 1', 'y : 2']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It is very helpful!